# XSL href clarification

Tags: xslt

I am new to XSL programming. So, please help me.
Is it possible to concat position() values in href

example:
`<xsl:Variable name="driveLevel" select="position()"/>`

```
<xsl:Variable name="FolderLevel" select="position()"/>
```

Is it possible to combine:

```
<xsl:element name="a">
<xsl:attribute name="href">
#<xsl:value-of select="concat($driveLevel,'_',$FolderLevel-1)"/>
</xsl:attribute> 

</xsl:element>
```

When I click on the href link nothing happens.

PLease help me

Comment: Provide sample input XML and desired output.

Comment: What does the output currently look like as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a concrete example we can't really help you. But in my case I am using it like this and it works fine.

```
<a href="#{concat($driveLevel,'_',$FolderLevel-1)}">
<xsl:value-of select="$linkName"/>
</a>
```